# Check if value is a Symbol in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, symbols

How can I check if a value is Symbol in JS?

I do not see a `Symbol.isSymbol(x)` method. My test of `(x instanceof Symbol)` does not seem to work either.

Comment: `typeof x === 'symbol'` works

Comment: `x instanceof Symbol` doesn't work because x is a primitive. If you cast x to an object that will work ie `Object(x) instanceof Symbol//true` However the accepted answer is still the best approach as long as you don't need pre-ES6 support.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Check it with typeof:

```
typeof x === 'symbol'
```

Comment: yes thanks, I finally discovered that in this article https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/metaprogramming-in-es6-symbols/

Comment: I guess it's a primitive not an object, maybe why instanceof does not work?

Comment: Yes, it is a primitive

Comment: Also, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol#Using_the_typeof_operator_with_symbols

Answer (score 7):

***Updated 2022: Go with the accepted answer!*** If you're working in an environment so outdated that *`Symbol` needs to be polyfilled,* then you'll know that already. You'll be excruciatingly aware of it. You'll be *haunted* by it. Then, sure, use my answer. Otherwise don't bother. `typeof x === 'symbol'` is almost definitely all you need these days.

---

In ES 2015 and up, `typeof x === 'symbol'` is all that's needed. But it won't work if you're transpiling your code to ES 5.1 or earlier, even if you're using a polyfill for the `Symbol` builtin.

Every polyfill I've seen, including the babel-polyfill, implements Symbol as an object (i.e. `typeof x === 'object'`) using a constructor function called `Symbol`. So in those cases you can check that `Object.prototype.toString.call (x) === '[object Symbol]'`*.

Putting it all together, then, we get:

```
function isSymbol (x) {
    return typeof x === 'symbol'
        || typeof x === 'object' && Object.prototype.toString.call (x) === '[object Symbol]';
}
```

<sub>*Note that I'm not using `instanceof` in the transpiled scenario. The problem with `instanceof` is that it only returns true for objects that were created within the same global context as the assertion being made. So if, say, a web worker passes a symbol back to your page, or symbols are passed between iframes, then `x instanceof Symbol` will return false! This has always been true of all object types, including the builtins. `instanceof` often works just fine, but if there's any chance of your code being in a "multi-frame" scenario as I've described, use with caution!</sub>

Comment: It doesn't matter if x was created with a constructor function called Symbol. If it's pre-ES6 then `Object.prototype.toString.call(x)` will return `'[object Object]'`

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way of testing for a symbol is indeed:

```
typeof value=="symbol"
```

But you may not want to rely on `typeof` because it will return `"object"` for symbols that have been cast to an object. Such symbols still function as symbols in every way and should not be dismissed.

Symbols that have been polyfilled for pre-ES6 browsers also return `"object"` when using `typeof` because the return type of `"symbol"` was not yet available before ES6.

In that case using `instanceof` might be your best bet:

```
Object(value) instanceof Symbol;// works in most cases
```

The above is faster than the last method below because of the extra overhead required for a try/catch. However `instanceof` fails in some cases such as on objects created in a different window or frame and therefore a different global environment.

Here is a method that solves all of the above problems. It works with symbol primitives, symbols cast as objects regardless global environment, as well as polyfilled `Symbol` designed to work in pre-ES6 JavaScript. The reason it works is because `Symbol.prototype.toString()` will throw if passed a value that is neither a symbol nor symbol object.

```
// Annoyingly complex, yet guaranteed to work

function isSymbol(value) {
    var isSymbol, type = typeof value;
    if (type=="object") try {
        Symbol.prototype.toString.call(value)// Throws if value is not a Symbol primitive or object
        isSymbol = 1;// This is only set if it didn't throw
    }
    catch(e) {
    }
    return type=="symbol" || !!isSymbol;// cast to boolean
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The most efficient way is to test the constructor of a value:

```
const result = (value && value.constructor === Symbol);
```

Comment: I assume `typeof` does this check under the hood along with 1 or 2 other checks?

Comment: `typeof` returns a string, which forces a string comparison between the value returned and the value you're testing upon (`typeof x === 'symbol'` will compare two strings), which is presumably slower than `value.constructor === Symbol` (i'd suggest that the latter compares two internal ids, probably numerical).

Comment: Just for fun, I ran a quick benchmark comparing the two approaches, and your one beats the accepted answer about 6 times out of 10. And there's really not much in it, it's a very close race each time. Not surprising, since `typeof` is heavily optimised while your solution is slowed by the need to check for truthiness and then access an object property. Ever-so-slightly faster when run ten million times (as I just did), but I'd argue that readability trumps that sort of tiny performance gain, and the average developer is more familiar with `typeof` than the `constructor` property.

Comment: @daemonexmachina I did some benchmarking myself and was surprised to discover that you're completely right, at least with v8 (did the tests with nodejs). I guess there might be some dedicated optimization in place on expressions like `typeof x === "knownTypeString"`. 

Another interesting discovery was that `!value` performs as fast as `value !== null && value !== void 0 && value === value` (the required minimum to access value's `constructor` property). I'd expect the type coercion to slow things down, but it seems to be well-optimized as well.

Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: The thing is it's not type coercion. `typeof` is an operator that takes anything and _returns_ a string, rather than coerce it into one. Because it's a native operator, it doesn't need type coercion or any other language feature that we as JS devs have access to. The implementation details can be much closer to the metal than anything you or I could write in our JIT-compiled scripting language. V8, for instance, is written in C++.

Comment: The type coercion I was talking about is the one happening with the `!value` expression.